# Can you change a 'Single Text' field to a Person field and not need to chnage the edit form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can you change a 'Single Text' field to a Person field and not need to change the edit form on the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "not need to change the edit form on the list"?

Comment: ignore that bit. Just need to change the column

Comment: Is Infopath configured?

Comment: We have enterprise and I believe we have used it before so perhaps it is. Can it be done in InfoPath then?

Comment: It is quite complicated to change from text to person fiels, because person field is a lot like lookup column and it is not plain value field, like choice or number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change type of single line of text to person. Best way is delete existing column and recreate new column with same name.